# Adding values of an association through pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, associations

I have an Association in which values are lists of lists containing an Integer and a DateObject. I would like to build a function that adds all Integers that have the same dates.

`assoc = <| "first" -> {{1,DateObject[{2019,1}]},{2,DateObject[{2019,3}]},{3,DateObject[{2019,7}]},{4,DateObject[{2019,1}]}}, "Second" ->{{1,DateObject[{2019,1}]},{2,DateObject[{2019,8}]},{3,DateObject[{2019,7}]},{4,DateObject[{2019,8}]}}|>`

I am looking for a function F for which:
`response  = F/@assoc`

Where respnse will result in:
`assoc =  <| "first" -> {{5,DateObject[{2019,1}]},{2,DateObject[{2019,3}]},{3,DateObject[{2019,7}]}}, "Second" ->{{1,DateObject[{2019,1}]},{6,DateObject[{2019,8}]},{3,DateObject[{2019,7}]}}|>`

Is there any clever pattern matching way to do this for the general case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** ***"Adding values (...) through pattern matching"***:

You can use  [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/<code>ReplaceRepeated.html)as follows:

```
rule = {a___, {b_, c_DateObject}, d___, {e_, c_}, f___} :> {a, {b + e, c}, d, f};

ReplaceRepeated[rule] /@ assoc
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
f1 = Map[Values @ GroupBy[#, Last, {Total[First /@ #], #[[1, 2]]} &] &];
f1 @ assoc
```

[image]

Also

```
f2 = Map[{Total[#[[All, 1]]], #[[1, 2]]} & /@ GatherBy[#, Last] &];

f2 @ assoc
```

> same result

```
f3 = Map[{Total[#[[All, 1]]], #[[1, 2]]} & /@ SplitBy[#, Last] & @* SortBy[Last]];

f3 @assoc
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Dataset[assoc][All, GroupBy[Last], Total /* First]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @kglr, this does solve my issues. I was hoping I could find a way to do this with rules or pattern matching, but perhaps that is the wrong approach!

Comment: @MathematicaUser, my pleasure.

Comment: @MathematicaUser, please see the update re suing rules and pattern matching to get the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way that uses version 12.1's shiny new [SubsetReplace](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetReplace.html):

```
SubsetReplace[x:{{_, d_} ..} :> {Total@x[[All, 1]], d}] /@ assoc
```

[image: result screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html).

```
Query[All, GroupBy[Last -> First] /* KeyValueMap[Reverse[{##}] &], Total]@assoc
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.